# Where can I find words and expressions which are dated and not found in today's dictionaries?

Tags: dictionaries

I'm having trouble understanding Charles Dickens book called *The Haunted House*. Could anyone tell me in which dictionary I can find parts I don't understand? Is there a dictionary for nineteenth century literature?

Comment: I like the way you've been handling the problem up to this point Hamed.  It is always a pleasure to decipher Dickens for you.  :)

Comment: My first thought would be the OED, but you may have to go to a library to get access to it.

Comment: thanks lumberjack, It is a pleasure likewise. I have the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary - 8th Edition but it does not help a lot.

Comment: There are words the OALD does not have? 19th century is not that far back. Anyway. You can just head over to [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/) and search *all* dictionaries at once.

Comment: Links to the original OED are online at ELU [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2574/24489).